# squashing commits in github without git bash or command prompt

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to squash all your commits to a github project without having to use Git Bash or a Command prompt?

For example if I fork the repository ProjectA/ProjectA to ProjectA/fishbeinb. I start a pull request and I commit code and changes 3-4 times to ProjectA/fishbeinb. I do this all without using Git Bash or a Command prompt. Is there any way squash these commits before pulling/pushing my code?

Comment: How do you plan to commit the changes outside bash/cmd?

Comment: My mistake I meant after I start a pull request I commit changes a few times. I'll edit that in.

Comment: And.. did you try doing it as you would normally do it?

Comment: I'm still a unclear of your scenario. Pull requests, yes. But subsequent commits (which you want squashed) still need to be made in git. Are you asking if you can make commits as usual (via bash, say) and then squash them outside bash/cmd?

Comment: I can edit the code directly from github's website by going to a specific file. After I edit it I 'Commit Changes'. If I do this multiple times it will say I have committed multiple times. I want to squash all of these commits into one so the merging process with the master file is easier.

Comment: @BenFishbein - that explains it. Well, github's interface would need to invoke git runtime to create and push commits. Just that the bash/prompt is hidden from you. Commit being a much more frequent activity than squash, github probably built this interface, but not for squash AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way of squashing commits through GitHub's webapp. You need to use git for that, on your local machine, before pushing the commits to GitHub.

Comment: Well at least now I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, one option is [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whaler/kjfaikbmbbkbnjjeiambmjchclpfkedf?hl=en) I wrote. It replaces the GitHub merge button with squash merge. Hope it helps!